# Family Tree using Java and MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, data-structures

I created a Family tree program in Java using MySQL database. The program consists that user will enter the details like name, father name, city, state. The data is stored to the database. And then if we enter any name it will search in the database and return the complete family tree.

I created a logic for it that if any name entered by user, it will search for the name and print the data then it will assign name with the father name and search again in the database, till no records found. It is working fine, but the problem arises when there is common name of two members. How to solve this, any approach will be appreciated.

I am attaching the code for the program.

```
private void btnSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtDisplay.setText("");
    str="";
    boolean b = false;
    name = txtName.getText();
    b = hasParent(name);
    if(b==true)
    getData();
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No Records");

    b = hasParent(name);

    while(hasParent(name))
    {
        getData();

    }
    txtDisplay.setText(str); 

}                

public boolean hasParent(String name)
{
    boolean b = false;
    b = DBManager.searchParent(name);
    return b;
}

public void getData(){
    Family f = new Family();
    f = DBManager.getFamily(name);
    str = str+"Name: "+f.getName()+"\t|| "+"Father's Name: "+f.getFatherName()+"\n\n";

    name = f.getFatherName();
}
```

Database access Methods:

```
      public static boolean searchParent(String name){
         boolean flag = false;
         int count=0;
         try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DBURL, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD);){
             PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select name from Family where Name=?");
             System.out.println(name);
             st.setString(1,name);
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
             if(rs.next()){
                 flag =true;
             }

             rs.close();
             st.close();
         }catch(Exception e){

         }
         return flag;
     }
```

Comment: People having the same name is a common problem in databases. You can never assume a name is a unique identifier of a person - you have to generate your own unique IDs or (if possible/desirable) use some sort of state-provided number, e.g driver's license number

Comment: Search through name is not a good way, you need to modify the logic for identification of key(here name) and the key must be unique then we able to search. So, we make a pair of <father and child> pair as a unique key. use father and child as key for search.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 tables.

The first containing the user data: ID, name, date of birth, date died (if applicable), ...
where`id` is just an auto generated unique number for each user.

The other table contains the "parent" relationship. This table has columns `father` and `son` for example. (or if you also want to add mother and siblings you could have the columns `person` `otherPerson` and `type` which defines whether it's the father, mother or sibling). These columns have as value the `id` of that specific person in the first table.

Then in your "user interface" you look up all persons with that name, print them out and have the user choose the correct one if applicable. You insert the `id` of the chosen person with along with that of the newly inserted person into that relation table.

Comment: The second table is not really necessary, as the relation is 1 to many, not many to many. You can put the father ID in the user's record. No user will have more than one father.

Comment: No more than 1 biological father yes. But it's less flexible if you ever want to expand it for a full family tree. Which is why I also hinted at the mother and siblings. If he only ever wants to keep track of the biological father to son relation then only an extra `fatherID` column is needed indeed.